# rollOver doesn't work as expected in AS 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, mouseover

guys!

I have a little problem making a hover effect on an object in Flash AS2. I want to make the object to go up (changing the Y) with objName.onRollOver = function() { -Y } and then to bring it back down like objName.onRollOver = function() { +Y }. But When I dont complete the operation in the function onRollOver (the Object did not reached it's final destination) Flash  triggers the onRollOut function and the object goes down (+y). How can I fix that with as2 or I have to migrate to as3?

Comment: "But When I dont complete the operation in the function onRollOver" = by moving the button up, the mouse is no longer over it, thus triggering the roll out, moving it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the y coordinate and restore it on rollOut:

```
objName.onRollOver = function() {
    if (objName.saveY === undefined) objName.saveY = objName._y;
    objName._y = objName.saveY - 1;
} 

objName.onRollOut = function() {
    objName._y = objName.saveY;
}
```